# window.close not working in firefox/chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I checked on duplicate threads but did not work. I just need to close browser after I click close. but it is firing Controller [HttpPost] method instead of close the browser.

browser is closing if open the same url from another window.

### view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
         .....
         ....
          <td align="right">
              <input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
              <input type="submit" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel" />
          </td>
 }
```

### JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
          ......  
          $("#btnCancel").click(function (event) {  window.close(); });
       });
```

### Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(List<CustomerCommPreferences> lstcustCommPref, bool chkSolicitation)
    {
    }
```

Console warning show `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.`

Comment: JavaScript can only close windows it has opened. It doesn't have control of the "parent" browser window like that

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close for more

Comment: you have assigned a submit button to your "close" feature which leads to a form submission. That's why it gets progressed by the controller. It is also a bad choice to force to close after clicking a button. If you want to provide a cancel feature, **redirect** the user instead of closing the window (which is less user friendly).

Comment: Submit buttons submit....

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can only close the windows it has opened.  For example:

```
var yourWindow = window.open('http://google.com');
```

You could then use `yourWindow.close();`

The reason why you are hitting the controller is because you have two buttons which are inside a `HTML` form.  When these buttons are clicked the form is submitted back to the server.